# AngularJS component not updating value to DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-components

Here is a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Z2tDrCycOHaEC9ot1mng?p=preview) link where i tried to create a service (factory) and a component which gets value from the service and displays on the template.

I am able to see the value reaching the controller function but then the DOM is not reflecting the values.  Need help in understanding how to keep 
DOM in sync with the component data.

```js
    //heroDetail.js
    (function(angular) {
      'use strict';
    angular.module('heroApp').component('heroDetail', {
      templateUrl: 'heroDetail.html',
      bindings: {
        hero: '='
      },
      controller: heroCtrl
    });

    heroCtrl.$inject=['mainManager'];

    function heroCtrl(mainManager) {
      var vm = this;
      
      vm.$onInit = function () {
        vm.hero = mainManager.hero;
        alert(vm.hero.name);
      }
    }
    })(window.angular);

    //index.js
    (function(angular) {
      'use strict';
    angular.module('heroApp', []).factory('mainManager', function mainManager() {
      
      let hero = {
        name: 'Spawn',
      }
      
      function makeSuperHero() {
        hero.title = 'Super Hero';
      }
      
      return {
        hero: hero
      };
      
    });
    })(window.angular);
```

```html
    <!--index.html-->

    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Example - example-heroComponentSimple-production</title>
      <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="index.js"></script>
      <script src="heroDetail.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="heroApp">
        <!-- components match only elements -->
        <div>
          <b>Hero</b><br>
          <hero-detail></hero-detail>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>


    <!--HeroDetail.html-->
    <span>Name: {{heroCtrl.hero.name}}</span>
```

Please use plunkr link since the snippet wont compile here.